# Why do I get an unchecked assignment warning?

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I have the following interface and class definitions...

```
abstract interface I{}

class Foo implements I{}

abstract class A<T extends I> {
    List<T> list;
}

class B extends A<Foo> {}
```

All the definitions work fine.  I then want to do the following:

```
A b = new B();
List<? extends I> iList = b.list;
```

The compiler will indeed give me an `Unchecked Assignment` warning... but why? Won't all of `A`'s lists be of type `<? extends I>`?  b.list always has elements that extend I, so I am having trouble seeing why there would be an error

Comment: `A` is a [raw type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1079354) at declaration.

Comment: But won't all of `A`'s lists be of type `<? extends I>`?

Comment: Nope - there's no guarantee of type safety with raw types, so anything to do with generics is completely off the table now.

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun that's a good question. You should add it to the text of your question instead of in a comment. That will make it much more interesting and different from the duplicate.

Comment: Is there a way to get unmarked as a duplicate? I still don't see any counterexamples to my comment, and now edit

Answer (score 2):

The variable `A b` is of a raw type. Perhaps you meant to use `A<Foo> b` instead.

Comment: Both good fixes, but does anyone see why? won't all of `A`'s lists be of type `<? extends I>`?

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun An `A<Foo>` is not an `A<? extends I>`, since you know that the generic type is more specific than that.

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun, I think its answered in the comments to your question. Basically define A as a generic type and then the Unchecked warning goes away from the second statement List<? extends I> iList = b.list;